# How to stop iOS devices from reducing volume after microphone access is granted?

Tags: ios, audio, volume, microphone

I've found that this has been asked a couple of times, but not particularly recently and not with any answers that have been useful.

My web app allows the user to grant microphone permission:

```
// Check if the browser supports the getUserMedia method
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      // Request microphone access
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(function(audioStream) {
          // Microphone access granted, do something with the stream
          console.log("Microphone access granted");
```

and to listen to the response when the audio is ready:

```
// Add an event listener for the custom event
document.addEventListener("audioReady", function() {
  audioElement.play()
    .then(() => console.log("Playback started"))
    .catch(e => console.log("Playback failed due to: ", e));
});
```

On Android and Windows devices, the audio plays back at the correct volume, but on iOS devices, the volume is reduced from the point that the user grants the microphone permission.

My understanding is that Apple have deliberately built this into the OS so that users are able to hear themselves when they speak into the microphone. For my app, the microphone will always be toggled off when the audio is playing.

I was wondering whether anyone has found a way to ensure that the volume stays up when the microphone is off (but permission has been granted). It seems possible in a native iOS app with Audio Session API, but I was wondering whether anyone had a workaround for a web app?

Thanks for any help.

I've tried setting the session to .playAndRecord with Audio Session API, knowing that it probably wouldn't work in the browser.

EDIT: In case anyone has the same problem in the future, I haven't been able to find any possible solutions. It seems like something the app will have to live with until I build a native iOS app.